# RXJS making calls synchronous

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In my service I have a code that fetches token from an iframe parent and used that token to do a rest call.

Below is the code snippet for the method that does the GET REST call.

```
public get_agencyschema() {
return this.tokenService.authenticatedToken.pipe(
  map(token => {
    const opt = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: token
      })
    };
    console.log('get_agency %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ' + token);

    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl', opt);
  }));
}
```

When I call this method from my component I get an undefined. Here is the code for my component.

```
private doSomething() {
this.rest.get_agencyschema().subscribe(data => {
  /* tslint:disable:no-string-literal */
  this.ccConfig = data['_embedded']['item'];
  /* tslint:enable:no-string-literal */
  for (let index = 0; index < Object.keys(this.ccConfig).length; index++) {
    if (Object.keys(this.ccConfig[index].configuration).length > 0) {
      this.Schema = this.ccConfig[index];
      // console.log(this.Schema);
      break;
    }
  }
  // console.log(this.Schema.configuration);
  this.LocationVerifyForm.setValue({
    MatchDistance: this.Schema.configuration.MatchDistance,
    IsReturnClosestMatch: this.Schema.configuration.IsReturnClosestMatch,
    WildcardCharacters: this.Schema.configuration.WildcardCharacters,
    IntersectionDelimiterCharacters: this.Schema.configuration.IntersectionDelimiterCharacters,
    MaxReturnResults: this.Schema.configuration.MaxReturnResults,
    IsDisplayHighAndLowCrossStreets: this.Schema.configuration.IsDisplayHighAndLowCrossStreets,
    IsDisplayHighAndLowCrossBlocks: this.Schema.configuration.IsDisplayHighAndLowCrossBlocks,
    IsDisplayBlockNumbersForIntersections: this.Schema.configuration.IsDisplayBlockNumbersForIntersections,
    DisableAutoSelectVerifiedLocation: this.Schema.configuration.DisableAutoSelectVerifiedLocation,
    IsDisplayTableOfContent: this.Schema.configuration.IsDisplayTableOfContent,
    DistanceInMeter: this.Schema.configuration.DistanceInMeter,
    Direction: this.Schema.configuration.Direction,
    IsFilterBeatsByCityEnabled: this.Schema.configuration.IsFilterBeatsByCityEnabled,
    CascadeLevel: this.Schema.configuration.CascadeLevel,
    BlockKeyword: this.Schema.configuration.BlockKeyword,
    BlockDisplayFormat: this.Schema.configuration.BlockDisplayFormat,
    BlockGeoCodeLocation: this.Schema.configuration.BlockGeoCodeLocation,
    IsRetainInvalidPremiseNumber: this.Schema.configuration.IsRetainInvalidPremiseNumber,
    GeoDatabase: this.Schema.configuration.GeoDatabase
  });
});
this.LocationVerifyForm = new FormGroup({
  MatchDistance: new FormControl(),
  IsReturnClosestMatch: new FormControl(),
  WildcardCharacters: new FormControl(),
  IntersectionDelimiterCharacters: new FormControl(),
  MaxReturnResults: new FormControl(),
  IsDisplayHighAndLowCrossStreets: new FormControl(),
  IsDisplayHighAndLowCrossBlocks: new FormControl(),
  IsDisplayBlockNumbersForIntersections: new FormControl(),
  DisableAutoSelectVerifiedLocation: new FormControl(),
  IsDisplayTableOfContent: new FormControl(),
  DistanceInMeter: new FormControl(),
  Direction: new FormControl(),
  IsFilterBeatsByCityEnabled: new FormControl(),
  CascadeLevel: new FormControl(),
  BlockKeyword: new FormControl(),
  BlockDisplayFormat: new FormControl(),
  BlockGeoCodeLocation: new FormControl(),
  IsRetainInvalidPremiseNumber: new FormControl(),
  GeoDatabase: new FormControl()
});
}
```

I am new to RXJS and Observables. Can someone please help me to find out the issue with as to get the response of GET method in the component method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you setting values to a form before the form is built? What is undefined? The subscription or the form? I have a better way for you to set values but I'm going to wait until I get more information.

Comment: The subscription is undefined, the variable `data` is undefined

Comment: @austinthedeveloper please help. I can give you more clarification if this is not enough. I am totally confused with this.

Comment: You're logging out data inside your subscription and nothing comes back? Sounds like something is wrong with your service http call, not the component code

Comment: @austinthedeveloper: the issue is caused because I am returning the `this.http.get()` from inside `this.tokenService.authenticatedToken` and hence I am getting an observeable object in the componenet. If I manually pass in the token and return the `this.http.get()` method then the data is successfully received in the component. Can you help me solve the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rxjs you would not "map" to a new observable but you would use "switchMap" (if always only one call could be active) or "mergeMap" (if multiple executions could run in parallel).

```
return this.tokenService.authenticatedToken.pipe(
  switchMap(token => {
    const opt = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: token
      })
    };
    console.log('get_agency %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ' + token);

    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl', opt);
  }));
}
```

Now you are returning the observable that will deliver the result of the http get call.

Comment: thank you @JanRecker that worked for me. This was really very helpful.